# Add one object to another set of objects in C++

Tags: c++, class, object

I'm working on my assignment in C++ course.

I have to create `operator+=` which will add an object to another set of object.

So, how do I implement operator+= here?

```
class classNew
{
    anotherClass *my_objects;
public:
    // TODO: classNew(int, char const *)
    classNew operator+=(const anotherClass & rhs);
};

int main()
{
    classNew d1(7, "w");
    anotherClass sgs[5];
    // somehow init sgs[0]..[4]?

    for (int i=0; i<sizeof(sgs)/sizeof(*sgs); ++i)
        d1 += sgs[i];
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

I have something like this

```
newClass newClass::operator+=(const anotherClass& seg){

this->my_objs[n_seg] = seg;

return *this;

}
```

Comment: How did they get added without `+=`?

Comment: Put a clean code sample showing what you have so far, it's hard to understand what you want from the writing here.  You can keep the question as is, adding the code should clear it up for us :)

Comment: @w00te I've update my question a bit with a code that I've written so far for the operator+=

Comment: I've added a literal code translation of your problem statement - is it correct?

Comment: Thank you so much it is very similar to what I have.

Comment: If the code version is accurate, I'll remove the old text: IMO code is better described by code

Comment: @Useless I guess the code describe almost everything what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: If there's something omitted, please add it to the code!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless your `operator+=` is intended to modify the object you're adding, which would be highly unusual, I'd suggest <strike>one</strike> two simple changes to the signature:

```
classNew & classNew::operator+=(const anotherClass& rhs);
```

You always want to return a *reference* to the class, otherwise you get a copy.

You have a pointer to `anotherClass` in your class, I assume that this is actually a pointer to an array. You simply have to copy the passed `rhs` to the appropriate spot in your array, reallocating it and growing it if necessary. If my assumption is incorrect, you just need to do whatever addition is defined as for your class.

If this weren't an assignment I would also suggest replacing the pointer with a `std::vector<anotherClass>`.

Comment: Hi @Mark, Thank you for the answer here. I've update a bit on my question about what I have written so far for my `operator+=` but not sure if that is the right way.

Comment: @Ali, your code update looks pretty good, but consider what `n_seg` should be.

Comment: @MarkRansom I've almost made the `rhs` object to be `const` similar to your suggestion.

Comment: I agree, it doesn't look like you have a problem unless n_seg is not <= length(myObjects) - 1 (mind c++ has no length function, but you get the idea :P )

Comment: @MarkRansom I'm a bit confuse on this. So say I use to have 10 object delacare then I want to add the one from main to make it 11 object so just use like `this->my_objs[n_seg] = seg;` this going to work?

Comment: @Ali accessing an array past its bounds is never going to end well.

Comment: @MarkRansom Sorry Mark, I'm kind of confuse what do you mean by "past its bounds" ?

Comment: @Ali the bounds of an array of size 10 are 0 to 9. If `n_seg` is outside of this range then you will get undefined behavior which is a very bad thing.

Comment: @MarkRansom Oh thanks I will keep that in mind and make sure it will not be exceed the size of it.